# can't use lookup_expr list in django_filters class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Url: `/user?u=root` works

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    u = django_filters.rest_framework.CharFilter(name='username', lookup_expr='contains')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','u']
```

but when i changed it to

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    u = django_filters.rest_framework.CharFilter(name='username', lookup_expr=['contains'])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','u']
```

url: `/user?u__contains=root` doesn't work.

django 1.11.1
django-filter 1.0.4
djangorestframework 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

Ykh is close, but incorrect. In your second example, the filter is still exposed as `u`, so filtering by `u__contains` is a no-op since it's not a recognized name. `u__contains` is *not* somehow translated into a `u__contains__contains` lookup.

Additionally, passing a list or tuple of lookups to `lookup_expr` might provide a different behavior than you would expect. It *is not* related to the automatic filter generation that you see with `Meta.fields`. Instead, it creates a multi-lookup filter ([docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filters.html#lookup-expr)). This filter has two inputs:

- a text input for the value to filter by
- a select widget to select which lookup to use

It accomplishes this by using a `django.forms.MultiWidget`, so your query would need to be something like `/user?u_0=root&u_1=contains`.

In general, `MultiWidget`s are not that compatible with API usage, given the `_0` and `_1` suffixes.

---

If you're trying to expose a filter named `u__contains`, you should do something like:

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    u = django_filters.rest_framework.CharFilter(name='username', lookup_expr='exact')
    u__contains = django_filters.rest_framework.CharFilter(name='username', lookup_expr='contains')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['u', 'u__contains']
```

Comment: thanks,i just want to know how to creates a multi-lookup filter . use /user?u_0=root&u_1=contains works.but i still did not find the doc about MultiWidget....

Comment: Do you mean the parameter suffixes? What are you looking for information on?

Comment: Your second code example is how you would create a *multi-lookup filter*. However, usage looks like `/user?u_0=root&u_1=contains`, which is kind of ugly. If you want to create *multiple filters*, you can use the `Meta.fields` [option](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filterset.html#fields). Does that answer your question? If not, can you more explicitly state what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes,it answer my question.thanks. but i didn't find the infomation on the document.how do you know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

And there are several ways to use lookup_expr and the way you write it is incorrect would be "icontains" for contain and "iexact" for exact. Also another well used expressions would be gte and lte.

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    u_contain = django_filters.rest_framework.CharFilter(
        field_name='username',
        lookup_expr='icontains'
     )
    l_exact = django_filters.rest_framework.CharFilter(
        field_name='lastname',
        lookup_expr='iexact'
     )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['u_contain', 'l_exact']
```